# Back button of Searchview

Tags: android

I'm using Toolbar and SearchView for the ActionBar. After submit query text, It's changed like the picture below. How to set OnClick to the back button?

[image]

Edit 1: Here are involve code

menu.xml

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

In my Fragment class

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        final MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(myActionMenuItem);
        final ImageView mCloseButton = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {
                if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
                    searchView.setIconified(true);
                }
                mCloseButton.performClick();
                return false;
            }
...
```

Comment: can you post your xml and java code

Comment: Read my Edit, pls!

Comment: you have made the toolbar xml also ,can you attach that also ? and you need search button on the top right.

Comment: setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: do you want to listen to the arrow click events??

Answer (score -1):

Simply add `android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"` in your menu item.

Example menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: doesn't answer the question, he's asking for a listener